# Neo4J - What happens to a directional relationship when one node is deleted?

Tags: neo4j, relationship

What happens to the relationship between nodes A and B when B is deleted (excluding detach delete)?

```
(a: A) - [r] -> (b: B)
```

Does the relationship `r` disappear? Does it still exist but point to nothing? Or would the delete transaction not complete because node B is still linked to node A via `r`?

I ask because documentation explains `DETACH DELETE` as deleting a node and any relationships it has with other nodes. How does Neo4J handle relationships when `DETACH` is not used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete a node if there is still a relationship on the node.
So the transaction will fail.

That's why the `DETACH DELETE` has been introduced.

Comment: Also,  when you have three nodes `(a)-[r1]-(b)-[r2]-(c)` and you `DETACH DELETE` nodes `a` and `c`, what happens to node `b`?

Comment: `a`, `c`, `r1` and `r2` will be deleted, but not  `b`

Comment: I just realised I posted the last two comments (deleted now) on the wrong question. My bad